# Encryption support the server name provided doesnt match the server name on the SQL server SSL certificate - Cannot connect to Azure SQL from Excel

Tags: excel, azure-sql-database, export-to-excel

I am attempting to connect to an Azure SQL server database from Excel. I have used the Microsoft account authentication option, logged in via Azure AD and MFA authentication, at the last step I get the error message below.

Encryption support

> The server name provided doesn't match the server name on the SQL server SSL certificate. Please contact your administrator; to see the link below for more information. Alternatively, you could change your connection encryption settings. Would you like to continue using an unencrypted connection ?

I know the source of the error relates to setting the encryption to yes or enabled etc and it should work, however there is nowhere to programmatically change the connection string.

This is making me think, whilst AD connection is by far the most secure way to connect excel to SQL server, I wonder if there are any other options.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to connect SQL server from Excel I selected Sql server as get data option enter the sql server name and used AD MFA authentication I got the below error:

[image]

I tried to connect by following below procedure:

Goto excel ->Data ->Other source -> From OLEDB

[image]

Click on build:

[image]

Select the provider and click on next:

[image]

Enter the name of SQL server Selected the Authentication mode, enter AD UID select the db:

[image]

Tested the connection:

[image]

Click on OK, After that will get Authentication window Enter only the username and click on connect

[image]

After clicking on connect I got Password Authentication and authentication option

[image]

After successful authentication it connected successfully to the database.

[image]